# Git接続が上手くいかない

Tags: git

いつもお世話になっています。
Git環境構築でどうしても先に進めないので、ご教授お願いできればと思います。

CentOS7+Apache環境に、GitLabを設置しています。
GitLabの設置までは完了しています。
SSH公開鍵を登録し、GitLab上で運用で来ているところまでは確認したのですが、SourseTreeやToutoisGitなどから接続するとエラーが出てしまいます。
どなたかご教授頂けませんでしょうか？

[前提]
CentOS7+Apache+GitLab
sshdのport設定は22から10022に変更済み
GitLabは4080ポート使用でApacheと共存させています。SSLあり。
Gitlabのアカウントは「test」メールアドレスは「test@test.com」とします。
Gitlabはサブドメインを使用し、git.test.comで運用しています。

~/.ssh/config等々セッティングして、

```
$ ssh git@git.test.com
```

で問題なくログイン出来ていると思います。（Welcome to GitLab, test!表示出ます）

```
Host git.test.com
  User git
  Port 10022
  HostName git.test.com
  RSAAuthentication yes
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/test/id_rsa
```

また、GitLabでプロジェクトを作成した際に提示される「Create a new repository」の手順通りにサーバー上で操作したところ、該当プロジェクト内にGitの操作履歴が表示されることも確認できています。

```
$ git clone git@git.test.com:test/test.git
$ cd test
$ touch README.md
$ git add README.md
$ git commit -m "add README"
$ git push -u origin master
```

ここまで確認できたので、SourseTreeやToutoisGitなどで接続を試みたのですが、以下のようなエラーが出ます。

```
FATAL ERROR: Network error: Connection refused
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

また、Git Bashで試みたところ、以下のようなエラーが出ます。

```
$ git push -u origin master

ssh: connect to host git.test.com port 22: Connection refused
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

調べて色々試してみたのですが、解決する事が出来ていません。
22番Portに繋ぎに行っているように見えるので、URLを
ssh://git@git.test.com:10022:test/test.git
のように試してみたのですが、結果は同じでした。
（繋がらなかったのでssh://git@git.test.com:test:10022/test.gitも）

eval `ssh-agent`
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
この辺りも試したのですが駄目でした。

config/gitlab.yml
ここに、「ssh_port: 10022」を設定する、と言う記述を見付けたのでそちらも試しましたが、それをするとGitLabのURLにアクセスした際502になってしまった為、今は戻しています。

「/var/log/messages」のログは、以下の通りです。

```
Sep  3 05:03:13 133-130-106-145 nm-dispatcher: Error: an inet prefix is expected rather than "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx".

「/var/log/secure」のログは、以下の通りです。
Sep  3 04:50:16 133-130-106-145 sshd[10846]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user git by (uid=0)
Sep  3 04:50:16 133-130-106-145 sshd[10848]: Received disconnect from 133.130.106.145: 11: disconnected by user
Sep  3 04:50:16 133-130-106-145 sshd[10846]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user git
```

何かどこかを間違えているのだと思いますが、どなたかおわかりになりませんでしょうか？
お手数お掛け致しますが、宜しくお願い致します。

Answer (score 1):

もしgitlabのインストールをomnibusパッケージ(`yum`でインストールされたのでしたらこちらでしょう)で行ったのであれば、編集すべきは`gitlab.yml`ではなく`/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb`です。
今回の場合であれば`gitlab_rails['gitlab_shell_ssh_port']`と書かれた行のコメントアウトを外して値を`10022`へ変更した後、`sudo gitlab-ctl reconfigure`コマンドを実行すれば反映されるはずです。

正常に反映されれば、各プロジェクトのトップページに記載されているURLも正しい値(おそらくは[yaegashiさんの書かれている](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/28663/2808)通り `ssh://git@git.test.com:10022/test/test.git`)に更新されます。

`~/.ssh/config`の編集は必須では有りません。

参考:

- [GitLab Documentation - Changing gitlab.yml and application.yml settings](http://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/settings/gitlab.yml.html#changing-gitlab.yml-and-application.yml-settings)
- [GitLab で使用する SSH のポート番号を変更する | バシャログ。](http://bashalog.c-brains.jp/14/11/18-151735.php)

---

(以下、上記とは関連のない別解です)

GitBash, SourceTree, TortoiseGit を動かそうとしているホスト(Windows)の方で `~/.ssh/config` を設定していないのではないでしょうか。
`git@git.test.com:test/test.git` でアクセスするためにはWindows環境でも同じ設定が必要です。

Comment: ご教授ありがとうございます！
gitlab.rbの編集をして、プロジェクトTOPページにURLが正常表示されるようになりました。gitlab.ymlを編集するとの記事を見付けて試行錯誤したのですが、場所が違ったのですね。助かりました。
上記URL修正だけでは動きませんでしたので、config設定の見直ししてみます。

Comment: URL設定を10022にしてみたのですが、相変わらずエラーが出ます。
ToutoisGitでは
「GitLab: The project you were looking for could not be found.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.」
GitBashでは
「Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.」
configの方も10022込みの設定になっています。

Comment: Git Bash から `ssh -p 10022 git@git.test.com`を実行するとどうなるでしょうか。正常であれば、"Welcome to GitLab, xxxx!"が表示されるはずです。
"Permission denied"等のエラーメッセージが出る場合には`-v`オプションを付けて`ssh -v -p 10022 git@git.test.com`を実行してみてください。エラー原因の詳細が出力されると思います。(ご自身で見てわからなければ、質問文に追記して頂けると回答できるかもしれません)

Comment: 何度も回答ありがとうございます！エラーが出ましたので、-vつけて見てみました。
`debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic  debug1: Next authentication method: publickey  debug1: Trying private key: /c/Users/xxx/.ssh/git/id_rsa  debug1: No more authentication methods to try.  Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).`最後のこの辺りを見ると、秘密鍵を見に行っていないのかな…と推測したのですが、ちょっと明日の夜まで細かく見る時間が取れません…折角回答下さっているのに、申し訳ありません。秘密鍵はパスワード付きで、Pageantにaddしてあります。また、config内に「puttykeyfile = C:\\sshkey\\id_rsa」と秘密鍵の位置は指定しています（ToutoisGitで設定したConfigですが）

Comment: 出力メッセージに`C:\\sshkey\\id_rsa`が全く登場していないのであれば、推測の通りだと思います。`ssh -v -i /c/sshkey/id_rsa -p 10022 git@git.test.com`という形で`-i`オプションでファイルを直接指定してみるとどうでしょうか(※git bash環境が無いのでパス指定合っている確認できていません)。 //Git Bashのsshにpagent設定を認識させるには追加の作業が必要だそうですが([参考](http://qiita.com/jkr_2255/items/f1ebd3fa4a9bf8ee1b03#pageant%E3%81%A8%E3%81%AF))、今これをやると問題が複雑化しかねないので今は取り敢えず忘れておきましょう。

Comment: 昨晩Git自体のバージョンも上げてみたりもしたのですが、特に状況変わりませんでした。-iも試してみたのですが、エラーメッセージに特に変化は無いように思います。出力ログを全て記載しても良いのですが、コメントではちょっと見辛いですね。一旦GitLabを関与させないGit接続を試してみようかと思います。（GitLab自体は動いているようなので同じ結果になりそうですが…）

Comment: GitLabを通さずGit管理は正常に動作しました。具体的には別途ユーザーgittestを作成し、/home/gittest/.sshにauthorized_keys作成、リモートリポジトリも/home/gittest/git/に作成し、SSH鍵認証アクセスする事で、正常にComit、Push出来ました。Git自体、またSSH接続自体は問題ないようです…。GitLab関係でどこか間違っているのだろうな…と思うのですが、もう一度全体見直してみます。

Comment: 何とかGitLabへのPushに成功しました。実は…色々試していたせいで成功した理由がいまひとつ判明せず…。GitLab系の設定は特に弄っておらず、Windows側は鍵を作り直したり、known_hostsを触ってみたり…と、そこまで触っておらず…。gittestユーザーでのテスト中にやった事と言っても、/home/gittest/以下の操作だったので、gitユーザーに影響が出るとはあまり…。鍵の作り直しも同じ要領で何回も試していたので、本当に原因がわからないのですが、一旦は成功しました。色々手探り初心者の良くないところです…。とは言え、gitlab.rbの書き方は大変助かりましたし、何よりログの見かたを知らなかったので、こちらが解析の際に大変役に立ちました。色々とアドバイスありがとうございました！

Answer (score 0):

URL 形式を使うのであれば

```
ssh://git@git.test.com:10022:test/test.git
```

ではなく

```
ssh://git@git.test.com:10022/test/test.git
```

が正しいのではないかと思います。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます！

不勉強で申し訳ないのですが、GitLab側に、
SSHなら「git@git.blackthrush.net:neko/roquest.work.git」
HTTPなら「http://git.blackthrush.net/neko/roquest.work.git」
とあったのですが、ssh://を付けずに設定しても通らなかったため、平素別のGitサーバーで記述しているように、頭にssh://を付けていました。
一度それで試してみます。ありがとうございます！